# java using two hashtables is better than one?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have 8000 key/value pairs. I read that hash speed is O(1), but with collision on key, it will become O(n) where n is log(item number), please correct me if my concept is wrong.

Then I think if I use multiple tables, say put 1 to 3000 in hashtable1, 3001 to 6000 to hashtable1, so the performance should have a higher chance to 2*O(1)? Besides, how can I determine the optimal size for table 1, 2 and so on?

Also, I read post that using hashmap is better if i do not use multi thread to access the hashmap? is it real?

Comment: Do not overthink things until it is proven that it is a bottleneck by a profiler, so use a single Map for all your keys. And yes, use `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable` class.

Comment: You can determine the optimal size by figuring out beforehand what the exact amount (or something that comes close enough) or entries will be (and set the size + loadfactor accordingly). Surely this is fairly straightforward..

Comment: i guess so, but i would like to know if this concept thinking is correct or not? thanks!

Comment: It is premature optimization, which is **the root of all evil**

Comment: For editors, only use "`" char to format as code, uhm, code. O(N) is not code.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of a collision depends only on the ratio between number of elements and size of the HashTable.

You can specify an initial value, if you don't, Java will handle this for you just fine.

Yes, use an HashMap if you have no concurrent access, since you won't have the extra burden of a synchronized data structure.

Comment: You can also specify a load factor, so you can tune the hashtable if its performance isn't adequate for your needs. Although often it can be a poor hash function for the keys as well.

Comment: let say 10 items, 3 of them after hash will become same key, will this ruin the hashtable performance, even if the ratio is small? thanks

Comment: @manhon if all them have the same key, looks more like a problem in your hashing method.

Comment: i dont know, i just use Java hashtable, and add some word to it, say 'apple', 'orange', i wont check if after hashing, those fruit will have same keys? or should i do anything to see if there is collision?

Comment: @manhon one more time: if your application presents performance problems, use a profiler to determine where they are. If the profiler shows that the problem is in the `Map` (`Hashtable`, `HashMap` or whichever implementation you use) operations, then start worrying about, otherwise, **don't**.

Answer (score 0):

You answered the question for yourself in the first sentence:  *I read that hash speed is O(1), but with collision on key*.

If the objects which are keys are of a class you wrote, then you have complete control over how `hashCode()` is computed.  Use a single map and implement `hashCode()` so that collisions are extremely unlikely.

If you don't control the way `hashCode()` operates, you can still write a class that wrappers the key objects and computes its own hash code for them - and the result will be easier to read than something which uses multiple maps.

The multiple map approach is a hack - and performance problems due to hash collisions are pretty rare - in most applications optimizing I/O and things like that pays far bigger dividends than this kind of micro-optimization.  So it's usually better to aim for readability.